# rent car from country to country

Tags: schengen, car-rentals

We are interested in traveling from Vienna to Prague,
We thought of renting a car in Vienna and finishing in Prague-Czech Republic.
The problem is that such rent from state to state costs quite expensive.
Anyone Have a Tip How to Find Cheap Car Rental?

Comment: As long as you can rent and return in the same country, the one-way fee is usually reasonable (tens of € instead of hundreds). For example, I was looking to rent in Frankfurt. Returning in Salzburg would be over €300 while returning in Munich would be €34.

Comment: It might be even hard to find a rental company in Austria which allows to drive its cars to Czech Republic. Many rental cars forbid drives to the countries of Eastern Europe.

Comment: @Neusser The Czech Republic is "eastern" Europe since the fall of communism? They're in the EU and surrounded by other EU countries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any car rentals in Europe that can be picked up in one country and dropped off in another?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47507/are-there-any-car-rentals-in-europe-that-can-be-picked-up-in-one-country-and-dro)

Comment: @DavidRicherby So? What the fall of communism changes in geography? East remains east.

Comment: @Neusser The easternmost point of the Czech republic is barely a couple of kilometres farther east than the easternmost point of Italy. Do you have a citation for your claim that EU car rental companies won't allow their cars to be taken there?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Europecar: "You are permitted to drive a Europcar rental car from the Netherlands to Andorra, Belgium, Denmark, Germany, France, Finland, Italy, Ireland, Luxemburg, Norway, Portugal, Austria, Spain (with the exception of Ceuta en Millila), the United Kingdom, Sweden and Switzerland". No Czech Republic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hertz Germany: "Mercedes- und BMW-Modelle, sowie Cabriolets, SUVs, Transporter und LKW, sowie alle Fahrzeuge der Hertz Prestige Collection und der Fun Collection **dürfen nicht** nach Kroatien, in die **Tschechische Republik**, nach Ungarn und Polen, in die Slowakei und nach Slowenien gefahren und/oder dort zurückgegeben werden."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renting a car to travel between two countries will always be expensive as the rental company have to get the car back again afterwards - which means sending someone to go and retrieve it.

Do you have to go by car? You can get a train from Vienna to Prague much more cheaply - with advance tickets from €14 according to [The man in seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/prague-to-vienna-by-train.htm)

Comment: Even if you absolutely have to have a car for your time in the cities (and you really don't need one unless you are travelling extensively outside the cities) it's going to be much cheaper to rent a car in Vienna, drop it off, take the train to Prague and rent another car there.

Comment: What about luggage? suitcases?
Is it possible to take in the train without a problem?

Comment: There will be as much room for your luggage on the train as in the trunk of a small car. Also, traffic in Prague is heavy and driving is unpleasant. You want to rely on the inexpensive public transportation, except the taxicabs, which are notoriously dishonest.

Comment: Another work-around is that one of you flies to Prague, gets the car, drives it to Vienna and meets the rest of the party. At the end, you return the car in Prague, and it's not a one-way anymore. Takes some extra time and effort, but is probably cheapest.